# How can I fix the logic in this code to make it count the vowels in android studio?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  Button button;
  EditText editText;
  TextView textView;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Setting object ids.
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOne);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    //onClick listener to count vowels on click and display them.
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        int vowels = 0;
        String userInput;
        userInput = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
          // check if character is any of a, e, i, o, u
          if (userInput.contains("a") || userInput.contains("e") || userInput.contains("i") || userInput.contains("o") ||
            userInput.contains("u")) {
            vowels = vowels + 1;

          }
          textView.setText(Integer.toString(vowels));
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

How could I make my code display the vowels in the string in the textview? Right now it just seems to count every letter and output it I cannot figure out what ive done incorrectly im using the java language in android studio.

Comment: You are passing the INT vowels value, that code works as expected. I'ts not clear what you are trying to achieve but check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32813128/15298643)

Comment: Its simple to search that [Count vowels in a string java](https://www.google.com/search?q=count+vowels+in+a+string+java)

Answer (score 2):

Your error is checking the entire string every time inside the loop.

`contains` method returns `true` no matter where in the string the thing you are searching for is.

So, if there is even one vowel, you will still count to full string length, because `contains` will always return true.

What you need to do is check every letter separately with `charAt` like so:

```
if (userInput.charAt(i) == 'a' || userInput.charAt(i) == 'e' || ...) {
    vowels = vowels + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
          // check if character is any of a, e, i, o, u
          if (userInput.contains("a") || userInput.contains("e") || userInput.contains("i") || userInput.contains("o") ||
            userInput.contains("u")) {
            vowels = vowels + 1;

          }
          textView.setText(Integer.toString(vowels));
        }
```

This appears to be the core of your algorithm. You have the comment "check if character is any of a, e, i, o, u", however, the following if statement doesn't do this. Instead it checks if the input contains any vowels.

So let's think about your comment..."check if character..." this first part implies that you first need to get **a single character** from the string. Presumably you want to get the one at the position `i`. Looking at [the documentation for String](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String), you will find that there is a `charAt()` method that does the job:

```
char c = userInput.charAt(i);
```

Now you can check if this character is one of the vowels you want:

```
if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u)
```

That was a lot of typing. We can do a similar check using `contains()`:

```
if ("aeiou".contains(c))
```

In words: if a string with only vowels contains the one letter we grabbed from the input string, then it must be a vowel.

**Side Note**

You can avoid needing `charAt()` by using a "for...each" loop syntax:

```
for (char c : userInput)
```

This will loop over each character in the string rather than looping over the indexes of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a String is an array so you need to check the characters instead:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int vowels = 0;
            //Character userInput;
            //userInput = 'a';
            String userInput = editText.getText().toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
                // check if character is any of a, e, i, o, u
                if (userInput.charAt(i) == 'a' || userInput.charAt(i) == 'e' || userInput.charAt(i) == 'i' || userInput.charAt(i) == 'o' ||
                        userInput.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                    vowels += 1;
                }
            }
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(vowels));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.